# Spirit X3 no matching function for call to 'move_to'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

Why this does not compile?
(commented `r3` will compile, but I want semicolon in the rule)

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct v
{
    std::string value;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    v,
    (std::string, value)
)

using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

auto r1 = rule<struct s1, std::string>{} = lexeme[+alpha];

auto r2 = rule<struct s2, v>{} = r1;

using ast = std::vector<v>;

auto r3 = rule<struct s3, ast>{} = *(r2 >> ';');
//auto r3 = rule<struct s3, ast>{} = *r2;

int main()
{
    std::string script("a;");
    auto begin = script.begin();
    auto   end = script.end();

    ast a;

    phrase_parse(begin, end, r3, space, a);

    return a.size();
}
```

Comment: Seems like the same bug described [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Single-element-attributes-in-X3-still-broken-tp4681549p4682073.html) which is [fixed in develop/master](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/a8e391bd99dddb3f9ece84bdb1bb9236b0a37cf7) and will be in boost 1.61. (I hope this is an appropriate comment, if it isn't I'll remove it)

Comment: @jv_ This answers my question, thank you!

Comment: @sms Were you able to solve the problem then? Maybe you could write an answer describing what you did so that the question does not remain unanswered. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jv_ suggested, I've downloaded [develop](https://codeload.github.com/boostorg/spirit/zip/develop) branch. After that the code worked without any changes.